# In 2015, have relative font sizes become unnecessary?

Tags: html, css

Browsers today (2015) have zoom controls which actually magnifies the entire page, no matter how the fonts where sized (using px, em or rem). I find it easier to code pages using px when there are many subcontrols etc.

Is it still necessary to use relative font sizes (i.e. using "em" or "rem")?

Comment: The question suggested as answering the question is from 2011 so the browsers mentioned are very old. I still think the question is relevant.

Comment: If there are newer and better answers to a question then they belong on the original question and not on a duplicate of it.

Comment: Ok. Can I open the other question and bump it so that it is found? Also, it is a bit problematic because the question also contains a fixed year which makes it out of scope...

Comment: You can edit it to improve it and nominate it for reopening.

Comment: Oh, I did not see that. Sorry for my ignorance and thanks for enlightening me!